# Return varying fields based on Route

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-routing

Laravel provides the "guarded" variable in the Model to hide certain fields from JSON, but I'd like to know how to return only certain fields for certain routes. For example rather than returning

```
Alert::where('alert_id', $id)->first();
```

which dumps all the fields not in the "guarded" array, for example:

```
id: 139
alert_id: "8336f6d2-e191-4014-9316-2c7c93e3ada2"
status: "notified"
member_id: 16
organization_id: 1
type: "timer"
minutes: 20
lat: "45.86"
lon: "-90.11"
address: "US Highway for Road 519, Chequamegon National Forest, Park Falls, WI 54552, USA"
phone: ""
created_at: "2014-07-16 14:29:07"
updated_at: "2014-07-21 11:08:01"
user_id: 0
```

I'd like to be able to specify, only return the "lat" and "lon" columns, **for this specific route only**.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful Laravel uses `guarded` or `fillable` (which is the opposite) to prevent mass assignment vulnerability and `hidden` to hide fields like `password` from your collections results.

As a general rule of thumb use this for `guarded` attribute for most of your Models:

```
protected $guarded = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
```

Now to call only specific columns do this:

```
$alert = Alert::select('id', 'lat', 'lon')->first();

return View::make('myview', compact('alert'));
```